# analytics realtime visitors on maps

Tags: javascript, php, loops, maps, analytics

I currrently have a function that tracks realtime visitors. This returns either an empty object, or an array of arrays, in the form of `$resulting[i][j]`, where:
`[i]` is each individual case, consisting of an array `[j]` with 6 pieces of information.
for example, `$resulting[0][0]` returns the city name of the first visitor. `$resulting[0][1]` results the latitude, `$resulting[0][2]` returns the longitude of the first visitor.
`$resulting[1][0]` returns the city name of the second visitor, et cetera.

`$resulting` is a two-dimensional php array. (if it contains data, otherwise it is empty)

In the same file, I have javascript which draws a google maps, and adds markers.
This uses `var markers = []`.
Now, currently the `markers[]` is a pre-set array. I would like to use the information from `$resulting` to set `markers[]`, such that it loops through `$resulting` and the coords used are from `$resulting[i][1]` and `$resulting[i][2]` respectively.

Below I have the relevant javascript variable and function.

```
// Array of markers 
         var markers = [
            {
                coords:{lat:52.0907,lng:5.1214},
                iconImage:'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png',
                content:'<h1>Utrecht</h1>'
            },
            {
                coords:{lat:52.0907,lng:5},
                content:'<h1>Links</h1>'
            },
            {
                coords:{lat:52.0907,lng:6},
                content:'<h1>Rechts</h1>'
            }

         ];

         // Loop through markers
         for(var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++){
             // add Marker
            addMarker(markers[i]);
         }
```

So, what I would like to do is the following:

`var markers` should be the results from `$resulting[]`, and `var markers[{ coords:{lat:,lng:}}]` should be `$resulting[i][1]` and `$resulting[i][2]` for all items in `$resulting[i]`

I hope it is clear what I am trying to accomplish. 
If somebody could give me some tips on how to accomplish this, or how to include these php sub-arrays in the javascript code? 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the PHP to JSON and assign it to a JS variable, then map each element of the array to an object containing the coordinates, like this:

```
const results = <? php echo json_encode($resulting); ?>;
let markers = [];

for(let i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    markers[i] = {
        coords: {
            lat: results[1],
            lng: results[2]
        }
    };
}
```

The result should be in this format:

```
markers = [
    { coords: { lat: 52.0907, lng: 5.1214 } },
    { coords: { lat: 52.0907, lng: 5.1214 } }
];
```

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. however it doesn't quite seem to work. in the php section I can echo json_encode($resulting) and it does in fact return an array like you specified, albeit, if there is 1 user online, in the form 
[["Eindhoven","5.469722","51.441643","Chrome","DESKTOP","1"]] However, the function in javascript does not seem to work, and in there I also cannot print out the variable markers.

Comment: I've updated the loop to make it a bit more obvious what's happening. You can now put `console.log` in the loop to do some debugging.